# How to inject Vue component using custom Vue instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I’ve seen some plugins that use custom Vue instance to invoke their own vue components. Something like

```
this.$activateLoadingBar.options({color:"Green", msg:"loading"})
```

Then a green loading bar pops up with “loading” as its message

I wanted to try and create myself. So I made a new component and declared a custom Vue instance by using

```
 Vue.prototype.$<name> = ...enter code here...
```

Then I am completely lost. What should I do so to get the result i needed ? I don’t know what is this method called, so i am unable search the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Global Event Bus. See the example below:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="sendMessageToChild">Send message to child</button>
    <HelloWord />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWord from '@/components/HelloWord.vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: { HelloWord },
  methods: {
    sendMessageToChild() {
      this.$root.$emit('messageToChild', 'any text');
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

```
<template>
  <div>x = {{ message }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWord',
  data() {
    return {
      message: '',
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$root.$on('messageToChild', text => (this.message = text));
  },
};
</script>
```

In this example, there is two components (a parent and a child). The parent component call the child.

But you can change this, the child can call the parent.

Otherhand, you can use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) or [Vue.observable](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-observable). But this is more complex if you are beginner.

Comment: Thanks, i use Vuex , but i don't know how to call $root.$emit in Vuex.

Comment: If you use Vuex, you musn't call `$root.$emit`. With Vuex, you must create a state and a mutation. The Global Event Bus is indicated for simple cases.